# Which conception of a " machine " allows to call "mechanical" Descartes and Hobbes views of nature and of science?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, descartes, explanation, hobbes

The word "mechanical" comes from a greek word meaning " machine".

However, the received definition of mechanical philosophy does not contain the concept of a machine. This school of thought is said to adopt the priciple according to which

> everything in nature can be explained by the size, the shape and the
>   movement of bodies or material objects ( one body acting on the other,
>   through collision)

My question : which concept of a " machine " allows to call "mechanical" such a principle.

Comment: There is no need for such a conception. Meaning of words shifts by loose resemblance without much attention to the original root. [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/mechanical) reports "mechanical" meaning "resembling machines, automatic, lacking spirit or spontaneity" c. 1600, from which it is a short step to "material forces of nature acting on inanimate bodies" from 1620s.

Comment: A lot of historical studies regarding the origins of modern science are about it... See e.g. Marie Boas, [The Establishment of the Mechanical Philosophy, Osiris (1952)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/301823?seq=1)

Comment: The connection is movement-machine: from pseudo-Aristotle's [Mechanica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanics_(Aristotle)) through Archimedes's [Equilibium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Equilibrium_of_Planes) and [Hero's machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_of_Alexandria) to Galileo's *Mechanics*. Machines are based on movement.